# Substraction between 2 Time columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I make a substraction of two columns of type *Time* in MySQL and get the result in minutes? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to convert to seconds and then back to minutes:

```
floor(time_to_sec(time1) - time_to_sec(time2) / 60) as MinutesDiff
```

Comment: You forget round brackets [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/36462/0) `floor((time_to_sec(time1) - time_to_sec(time2)) / 60)` or using integer division `(time_to_sec(time1) - time_to_sec(time2)) DIV 60 AS MinuteDiff`